# Neutral Kaon Decays to positively/negatively charged Pions

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction

$K^{0}$ meson consists of a $d$ quark and an $\bar{s}$ antiquark.
Its antiparticle $\bar{K^{0}}$ consists of an $s$ quark and a $d$ antidown quark.

$$|K^{0}\rangle=|d\bar{s}\rangle$$
$$|\bar{K}^{0}\rangle=|\bar{d}s\rangle$$

There are two versions of $K^{0}$ meson. One of them is the K-zero-long:

$$K_{L}^{0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[|K^{0}\rangle-|\bar{K}^{0}\rangle\right]$$

**My question is how can both decays be possible, as in my opinion the decay to electron violates conservation of lepton number. And is this interaction only possible via Z-Boson in the std. model?**

$$K_{L}^{0} \xrightarrow{weak} \pi^{±} e^{\mp} \nu_e.$$

Comment: That should be electron+antineutrino or positron+neutrino.  Lepton number is conserved, and the process runs via W, not Z.

Comment: lepton number is conserved by the appropriate neutrino for  positron, antineutrino for electron

Comment: so for example in the wikipedia article for the kaon (table) it is implicitly assumed with $\nu_e$ that the appropriate choice for the neutrino has to be made?

Comment: yes, in order not to write explicitly two lines